# Screenshots to upload my app?

Tags: android

I want to make 2 quick screenshots for the app am putting in the market.. But problem is when i signed the app for the market i can't transtef it to my phone and install the .apk.. Its not working..

Am using Eclipse. And i can't realy find a way to like make it an .apk that i can install from the phone cus the signed apk seems to not work..

Is there some other way i need to do so i can install this apk ?
And when i signed the app what do i need the certificate for?? When uploading it doesn't say anything about i need it..

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're not signing your application correctly. Have you tried reading this? It's very helpful:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Also, you should be able to just run the application on your phone from Eclipse and take your screenshots using Android SDK's built-in screenshot functionality from the Devices view.

Comment: How do i make the screen shots in the Virtual phone then?

Comment: From the emulator? You don't need to use the emulator for screenshots, you can just connect your phone and run your application directly from Eclipse.

Comment: But i what could posibly go wrong with the signing of the .apk.. I folowed all the steps from the wizard and uploading the .apk on the market doesn't seem to be any errors there..

Comment: Have you enabled support for unknown installation sources on your phone? This needs to be enabled if you want to install applications that are not from Market.

Comment: I will take a look.. Where do i find that option?

Comment: Oh i found it but it was checked.. And i have another .apk that works to install.. Realy strange.. But am running on Darkys rom maybe that is messing it up or somethin?

Comment: Oh, right. I'm really not sure what seems to be the cause of your issue then. Like I said, my first assumption was a problem with the signing of the application, but if that's not it, and it works well when installing from Market, then I'm not sure. I do, however, think that you should easily be able to do screenshots directly from within Eclipse - that's what I do :)

Comment: Do you have an existing version installed that is signed with a different key?